# my linked list not filling C

Tags: c, file, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to fill a linkedlist (dic).

`dataPtr` will be a word coming from kitap.txt file and `ID` will be 0,1,2 sequentally.

I couldn't fix this, can you see anything wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_LENGHT 30

typedef struct numnode//MY STRUCTURE
{
    char dataPtr[1000];
    int ID;
    struct numnode* next;

} NUMNODE;

typedef struct num
{
   NUMNODE* head;
} NUM;

//////
//////
//////

int main()
{
    char word[1000];
    int total=0;
    FILE *test= fopen("kitap.txt", "r");

    NUM* dic;
    dic=(NUM*)malloc(sizeof(NUM));
    NUMNODE* temp;
    temp=dic->head;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(NUMNODE));

    while (!feof(test))//getting all words and trying to fill linkedlist
    {
        fscanf (test, "%s",word);
        strcpy(temp->dataPtr,word);//filling dataPtr part
        temp->ID=total;//filling ID
        printf("%d-%s\n",temp->ID,temp->dataP1tr);//i can print here but its not filling
        total++;
        temp=temp->next;
        temp=malloc(sizeof(NUMNODE));
    }

    //printf("-----------");
    FILE*file= fopen("kitap.txt", "r");
    //FILE*dictionary=fopen("dictionary.txt","w");

    temp=dic->head;//point to head
    /*while(!feof(file))//trying to print linked list
    {

        printf("%d-%s\n",temp->ID,temp->dataPtr); //it only prints head node
        temp=temp->next;
    }       
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to exchange these two instructions :

```
temp=temp->next;
temp=malloc(sizeof(NUMNODE));
```

with these:

```
temp->next=malloc(sizeof(NUMNODE));
temp=temp->next;
```

Comment: well it worked but when i try to print list it prints all list
but also prints extra meaningless item and closes itself

Comment: remember to assign at the last item in the list the temp->next = NULL